# Rails 4: Iterate through an array to create model in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, model

I pass parameters from a view to a controller. The parameter is an array that is generated by the user. The user can add as many items to the array as they want. I want to iterate through this array to create multiple model objects in the DB. How can I go about doing this?

A person can create a meal, and within the meal form, there are options to add as many food items as they wish.

```
def create
    @meal= Meal.new(question_params)
    food_options = params[:food_options]
    i = 0
    if @meal.save
    food_options.each do |x| 
        @meal.foods.Create(:drink => food_option[i], :meal => @meal)
        i = +1
     end
   redirect_to @meal
else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use accepts_nested_attributes_for and let Rails handle it for you.

In the models/meal.rb

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foods
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :foods   # <==========
  ...
end
```

and in the controller, include the nested attributes:

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @meal= Meal.new(question_params)
    redirect_to @meals
  else
    render 'new'
  end
  ... 
  def question_params
    params.require(:meal).permit(...., foods_attributes: [ :drink, .... ])  # <====
  end
end
```

Comment: I originally went this route, but this only works if you pre-define how many food models the user can make in the beginning. Rather than limit how many food items a user can supply, I want the user to generate as many as they want.

Comment: This should work for any number of food items. Perhaps it is how you increase the new food items in the view so that it comes back as the expected format in the params hash.